# Get string from object in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

In Swift 2.3 I had the following code:

```
  func getMyName() -> String {
        return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("account")!["name"] as! String
    }
```

Now, I am trying to convert this code to Swift 3, but I am struggling with this error:

> Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Here's my migrated code:

```
func getMyName() -> String {
    return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "account")!["name"] as! String
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UserDefaults has a method called dictionaryForKey exactly for that:

```
func getMyName() -> String {
   return UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "account")?["name"] as? String ?? ""
}
```

Comment: @Leo Dabus Thank you for your help! That works. Could you please explain this error in more detail? Unfortunately, I also get this error for: `data[0]["fooBar"] as! String` (`data` is an array).

Comment: UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:) returns an object of type Any which may be a dictionary or not. You could use objectForKey but you would need to cast from Any to [String:Any] to be able to use the dictionary subscript.

Comment: if your data is an Array of Any `[Any]` you can access data first element and cast it from Any to Dictionary `[String: Any]` as follow `(data.first as? [String: Any])?["fooBar"] as? String ?? ""`